Why checking email in mailtrap I see unexpected support signature?
In Laravel 10 app I send an email with notification :
class ContactUsSentNotification extends Notification  implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Queueable;

    protected ContactUs $contactUs;
    protected User $manager;

    public function __construct(ContactUs $contactUs, User $manager)
    {
        $this->contactUs = $contactUs;
        $this->manager = $manager;
    }

    public function via(object $notifiable): array
    {
        return [ConfigValueEnum::get(ConfigValueEnum::NOTIFICATION_TARGET, 'mail')];
    }

    public function toMail(object $notifiable): MailMessage
    {
        return (new MailMessage)
            ->line('Contact Us message sent')
            ->line('Dear ' . $this->manager->name . ', ')
            ->action('Notification Action', url(route('admin.contactUsFeedback.index')))
            ->line($this->contactUs->author_name . ' (' . $this->contactUs->author_email . ') sent "' . $this->contactUs->subject . '" message:')
            ->line($this->contactUs->message )
            ->line('As manager of the "' . (ConfigValueEnum::get(ConfigValueEnum::SITE_NAME)) . '" site you need to accept it.')
            ->line(PHP_EOL . ConfigValueEnum::get(ConfigValueEnum::SUPPORT_SIGNATURE));
            // I added support signature which with config app is read from database
    }

But when I check the email in mailtrap I see ending support signature :

It use APP_NAME var from .env file, but I have these lines? Some default options ? How to find and delete them ?

You may need to customize the template. See https://laravel.com/docs/master/notifications#customizing-the-templates

first time seeing this type of sending email instead of blade. pretty cool.

@aynber, thanks it helped! If you answer in responce I will accept it

Laravel has a default template for sending emails, if you don't specify a view. You can customize the template per https://laravel.com/docs/master/notifications#customizing-the-templates by running this on the command line:
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-notifications

Which creates a file in resources/views/vendor/notifications/email.blade.php. The section you're looking for is the Salutation, which looks like
@if (! empty($salutation))
{{ $salutation }}
@else
@lang('Regards'),<br>
{{ config('app.name') }}
@endif

Alternatively, per this answer, you can change the salutation and greeting with ->greeting() and ->salutation() when you build your mail message.
